# exchange online transport rule for only one recipient?

Tags: exchange

Is there a way to write an exchange online transport rule (using GUI) to fire ONLY when there is only one recipient?  I tried multiple variations of Header Matches looking for a comma as a separator for multiple addresses, but the match pattern only appears to be applied to each individual To: address rather than the full To: header

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, you cannot trigger the transport rule by the number of recipients.
When I create a transport rule in EAC, I see that there are no options regarding the number of recipients in the optional conditions.
You can trigger transport rule when the recipient is a specific person.

Comment: Thank you Joy Zhang.  I know there are no options provided, that was why I was attempting to use "Message Header matches" option.  The regex should work, but for some reason does not - all I was trying to do was match the entire To: header to see if a comma separator was present.